# array_map 2d array to 1d associative array

Tags: php, arrays, lambda, array-map

I have a 2d Array (returned from PDO MySQL DB) that is of the form

```
{
  [0] => {
    "ID" => 1,
    "Name" => "Name1"
  },
  [1] => {
    "ID" => 2,
    "Name" => "Name2"
  },
 [2] => {
    "ID" => 3,
    "Name" => "Name3"
  }
}
```

Is there an elegant/efficient solution to transform it to

```
{
  [1] => "Name1",
  [2] => "Name2",
  [3] => "Name3"
}
```

I know I could loop through and create the array that way, but i feel like that may be less efficient than something like a fancy array_map.

Basically I want something like...

```
array_map(
  function ($value) { 
    return $value['ID']=>$value['Name']; 
  }, $ResultArray);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using PHP5.5 then you can use the `array_column` function - [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$names = array_column($records, 'Name', 'ID');
```

Otherwise, an `array_map` solution is probably as good as you can get:

```
$names = array_combine(array_map(function($value) {
     return $value['ID'];
}, $records), array_map(function($value) {
     return $value['Name'];
}, $records));
```

[Here's the array_combine docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)